# jQuery UI DateRangePicker Validate Not Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, daterangepicker

**tl;dr: How do I prevent blank dates from being entered in jquery-ui-daterangepicker?**

I am using http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/ and I am having trouble validating that a date range was selected. I intend to keep the `#export_date_range` `daterangepicker` open until a valid date range is selected, then use the selected date range to generate a CSV of data within the selected date range.

Here is what I am doing to initialize the `daterangepicker`:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Creates the daterangepicker.
    $('#export_date_range')
        .daterangepicker({
            initialText: 'Select Date Range',
            applyButtonText: 'Export Date Range',
            clear: function() {
                // Keep the daterangepicker open.
                $('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('open');
            },
            cancel: function() {
                // Close the modal.
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
            },
            change: function(event) {
                var selected_range = $('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('getRange');

                if (selected_range === {}) {
                    // No date range is selected.
                    // Alert the user.
                    alert('Select Date Range');
                    // Reopen the daterangepicker.
                    $('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('open');
                } else {
                    // Set the start date and end date.
                    var start_date = selected_range.start.getFullYear() + '-' + (selected_range.start.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + selected_range.start.getDate();
                    var end_date   = selected_range.end.getFullYear() + '-' + (selected_range.end.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + selected_range.end.getDate();

                    // Perform an AJAX to generate and download the CSV.
                    getCSV(start_date, end_date);
                }
            },
            close: function(event) {
                if (event.currentTarget.innerText === 'Export Date Range') {
                    // Trigger change event?
                    // $('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('change');
                    // daterangepickerchange
                    $('#export_date_range').trigger('daterangepickerchange');
                }
            }
        })
        // Open the daterangepicker.
        .daterangepicker('open');
});
```

When I call `$('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('getRange');` inside of the `close` callback, it always returns `null`. I believe the `#export_date_range` `daterangepicker` is de-initialized when the `close` callback happens, so I cannot retrieve the selected date range.

I am thinking of triggering the `daterangepickerchange` event on the `#export_date_range` element inside of the `close` callback, but I am not yet having any luck.

Comment: What happens if you do $('#export_date_range').val()?

Comment: create a jsfiddle which will help someone to answer

Comment: @Luke Becker  

Here is the input:  

`<input type="text" id="export_date_range" value="none" />`  

Here is what I have in the `daterangepicker` `close` handler:  

`console.log($('#export_date_range').val());`  

When I click `Apply` without selecting a date range, the result is `none`  

When I click `Apply` after selecting a date range, the result is still `none`

Comment: @MamunSardar here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/rtwoeuzf/19/

Comment: @MichaelHurley when I run the code provided, console.log($('#export_date_range').val()); returns an object with the start and end time.  I also don't see an apply button, but if I select a date range and click "Export Date Range" it appears to work and logs a date in the developer console.

Comment: @LukeBecker where are you calling `console.log($('#export_date_range').val());`? My intention is to get the selected date range in the `close` callback on line 739  
http://jsfiddle.net/craftman32/rtwoeuzf/44/

Comment: @MamunSardar @LukeBecker thanks for the help! The `setTimeout` solution worked for me. In addition, I found a way to set the default date range to the current week:  
`$('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('setRange', {start: moment().startOf('week').startOf('day').toDate(), end: moment().endOf('week').startOf('day').toDate()});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get value by `$('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('getRange')` only after the `close` finishes execution. So on `close` event you can't use that directly, cause you'll get the previous value, which is empty for the first fired event. You can apply a timeout trick to let the `close` event finish. like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var range = $('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('getRange');
    console.log(range);
    if (!range || !range.start || !range.end) {
      // The user clicked outside of the daterangepicker.
      // Reopen the daterangepicker.
      $('#export_date_range').daterangepicker('open');
    }
}, 10);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtwoeuzf/53/